# CiviMember Range Price: Automatically assign Membership based on $amount paid

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

We are looking to have ranged membership prices e.g.

$5-59 = Level 1
$60-99 = Level 2
$100-499 = Level 3

CiviCRM seems to support a "minimum price" for membership. How do we make it a range between minimum and maximum?

Also, these ranges should support recurring contributions (yearly).

Nice to have: 
* Ability to make a sliderfield out of the range

CiviCRM 4.7.x - drupal 7

Comment: stating your CMS is always worth doing!

Comment: Sorry, drupal 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can totally do this out of the box with Webform CiviCRM module!

Sorry for the swim squad references - but that's the project I was on when I read your question - here's a quick demo:

- in CiviCRM Tab -> add Membership Type - User Select; also add Membership Fee field;
- in the Webform tab -> ensure the Membership Type is a Listbox; Use static to only get the ones you need on this form;

Then under Webform Tab -> Conditionals - just a quick example - but you can make this as complex as you like - and even combine statements (is greater than or equal and is less then) to cover your $ ranges.

[image]
This says -> if we type in 25 -> we automatically get option1 -> which is my case is White Squad Membership; note how Webform is clever enough to grey out the Membership Type so the user can't self select anymore;

[image]

And if we type in 50 or higher -> we automatically get option number 2 -> in my case: a Black Squad Membership

[image]

**PS - and you're going to get that slider in D8:**

[image]

Comment: Great answer! PS you don't have to wait for D8 to use https://www.drupal.org/project/sliderfield

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know that one yet :-)

Comment: I have no idea if it works with webform conditionals and webform_civicrm but if they've written their code properly it ought to.

Comment: Ok give me a minute :-)

Comment: Slider is not working out of the box for me for the Membership Fee field - i.e. without reading the instructions; I may try later!

Comment: Ok got the slider to work - but it's not working w/ conditionals to set the Membership Type field - so not an option (yet);

Comment: So to be clear, the slider doesn't work, but a regular textbox does?

Comment: Yes! See my screenshots

Comment: @Zachary don't forget to up-vote & accept Karin's answer :)

Comment: I"m trying it this morning and will report back with how far I can get. Thanks KarinG

Comment: Let me know if you have any Q 

Comment: One more question. I want to have 3 of these fields where a user can enter an amount, not one. Is that possible on 1 webform? I love your suggestion where it is one box, and the conditionals pick the membership, but our membership team insists on having 3 locations for someone to put in an amount for that level (between X and Y amount). If not, I could have a splash page which directed to three forms, or use blocks or something.

Comment: Sorry Zach - I don't understand why one would want 3 fields? What would that look like? How would that work - to have 3 locations to pick an amount between X and Y? Would you want to sum the 3 amounts? Sorry - not understanding what your Membership team is looking for; do they have an example somewhere you can show us?

Comment: BTW, I am currently trying to convince them it's overly complicated ;) It would look like your model, times 3. The first field "Level 1" would accept between $5-59 and apply the Level 1 Membership. The second field would be "Level 2" and accept between "$60-99" and apply the Level 2 Membership. They want people to realize a membership is worth the maximum, but accept less for those who can not afford. They want to clearly differentiate the levels, so having just one field with an input box would not do that (necessarily). Would just putting a table/chart with levels above be a compromise?

Comment: I am counter proposing the model you have proposed FYI because it passes my internal sanity check, whereas the other model just irks me for some deep reason.

Comment: Yes to a graph/chart! You don’t want 3 input boxes - unless you know what you want to do with the 3 (sum them? or take the max?);

Comment: Exactly, they dont want them to be a sum but just offered as choices. Its like they want radio buttons where each button is a ranged/slider

Comment: Radio sliders - ok that would be a cool widget 

Comment: I set up your demo (answer accepted). A quirk seems to be that they can choose membership options from the dropdown before setting their price. I used a conditional to solve that, too. Woot!

Comment: Yes - exactly :-) So powerful!

Answer (score 0):

if you need this only on the front facing forms then some javascript might do the required. ie have a single field for them to put the amount in, and behind the scenes figure out which Memb Type it should be and set that to 
 selected. sorry i can't offer a recipe.

Comment: Hey Petednz you've been overwhelmingly nice in helping me out! I still feel the need to tip you somehow. 

Here's my "crazy" idea. I'll set up a price set and have a price field for each level.

Each price field will be a select field with options entered in a painstaking fashion  (e.g. Level 1 = Membership type = 5$, Level 1 = Membership type = $6 (in $1 intervals).

Then, I'll use the jQuery UI (hopefully) to turn the select fields into a slider for the front end. 

On the back end, the staff could still pick the price set option that was the correct $ amount in the sliding scale.

Comment: I also had a thought that perhaps I could take your route and then use Webform CiviCRM to essentially be a passthrough for contributions where the user puts in an amount and then somehow use the rules extension or the drupal rules module to create the memberships. But- I perceive this might actually be harder than the above.

Comment: ouch that sounds painful. surely the javascript can work through going, if this is less than x then set it to $x, if it is below y set it to $y so you would only have 1 price set per range

Comment: Actually WEBFORMS rock. You should be able to do this easily using Conditionals based on the amount someone enters.

Comment: oh too late. good write up Karin ;-)

Comment: don’t forget to vote it up Pete 

Comment: Thx for the poke. assumed i would have when i first saw it.